# Inequality question.

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ with $a+b+c=1$. Show that $$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \leq 3 + 2\cdot\frac{\left(a^3 + b^3 + c^3\right)}{abc}$$

Ohhhkk. So first off,

\begin{align} a^3 + b^3+ c^3 & =a^3 + b^3+ c^3- 3abc +3abc\\
& =\ (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca))+3abc\\
& = \ (1-3(ab+bc+ca)) + 3abc \\
\end{align}

Using this the inequality becomes,
  $$7 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) \leq 9+ \frac{2}{abc}$$

How do i proceed from here? Was this the right approach? Is there a better one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following is a smooth enough.

We need to prove that:
$$(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\leq3abc+2(a^3+b^3+c^2)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3-a^2b-a^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Your second inequality it's indeed just the first:
$$7\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\leq9+\frac{2}{abc}$$ it's
$$7(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\leq9abc+2(a+b+c)^3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(3abc+2a^3+6a^2b+6a^2c+4abc-7a^2b-7a^2c-7abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3-a^2b-a^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-ab^2+b^3)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)\geq0.$$

Comment: Hmmmm very elegant $+1$. Also could you please explain how would we have proceeded from my second inequality? Or should i abandon that approach entirely?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Just expand and you're done.

(As per Michael's first step) Expanding out the denominator and homogenizing, we WTS

$$ (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) \leq 3 abc + 2(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$

Expanding terms and cancelling $abc$, we WTS

$$ a^2b + b^2 a + c^2 b + b^2 a + c^2 b + a^2 c \leq 2 (a^3 + b^3 + c^3).$$

This should be obvious / well known e.g.

$a^2b + b^2 a + c^2 b \leq a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ and $b^2 a + c^2 b + a^2 c \leq a^3 + b^3 + c^3$.

---

Unsurprisingly, since you applied an identity (as opposed to an inequality), we can follow the same steps of homogenizing using your approach.

We WTS

$$ 7 (ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)   \leq 9 abc + 2(a+b+c)^3$$

Expanding, and cancelling common terms, this becomes:

$$ a^2b + b^2 a + c^2 b + b^2 a + c^2 b + a^2 c \leq 2 (a^3 + b^3 + c^3).$$

Comment: where does $a^2b + b^2a + c^2 < a^3+b^3+c^3$ come from?

Comment: @Alex It's a [standard application](https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/#application-of-am-gm-on-terms-obtained-after-rearranging-creatively) or AM-GM. Hint: $a^3 + a^3 + b^3 \geq 3a^2b$.

Comment: I see. For me it's neither standard nor obvious

Comment: @Alex Practice more :) This "well-known inequality" also follows from [Rearrangement](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/) and [Muirhead](https://brilliant.org/wiki/muirhead-inequality/) pretty directly, so try proving them using these methods.